# Working with two 2D arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, javafx

I didn't exactly know how to word the title, but here is my problem:
I'm making the Conway's Game of Life in JavaFX, and I have two 2D arrays in different sizes. One array works as the game-board/grid, and the other works as the pattern I want to insert onto the board. Say the first array is 60x60, and the second is 3x3.
To make the board and the pattern, I use something like this:

```
//Board
for (int x = 0; x < 60; x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < 60; y++)
    board[x][y].setNextState(false);
    gc.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
    gc.fillRect(x * 10, y * 10, 9, 9);
  }
}

//Pattern
for (int x = 0; x < pattern.length; x++)
  for (int y = 0; y < pattern[x].length; y++)
    if (pattern[x][y] == 1) {
      board[x][y].setNextState(true);
    } else {
      board[x][y].setNextState(false);
    }
    gc.setFill(board[x][y].getState() ? Color.rgb(244, 92, 66) : Color.LIGHTGRAY);
    gc.fillRect(x * 10, y * 10, 9, 9);
  }
}
```

When done as above, the pattern gets placed top left on the board. But say I want it placed in the middle, I would have to use something like x = 30 and y = 30 in the pattern loop, but that wouldn't work in the `if (pattern[x][y] == 1)` line. How can I make this work?

I'm terrible at explaining, but I hope I made my question clear!

Comment: It seems that `pattern` is not 2D array, so you can't use `pattern[x][y] == 1`.

Comment: @ShekkarRaee I'm sorry, I didn't specify it in the snippet I posted. I made the int[][] pattern = {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}};, so that's not the issue. I can draw the pattern on the board just fine, I just can't place it anywhere else than in the top left corner

Comment: you have to define the position of your pattern relatively to the left-top of the board. Let's say we call them `posX` and `posY`, each time you will refer to the position of one pattern element relatively to the board, the position will be `x+posX` / `y+posY`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply an offset to the xy position when refering to the board and keep unchanged when refering to the pattern. Be aware that offsetX cannot be > of board width - pattern width, same for Y :

```
int offsetX = 30;
int offsetY = 30;
for (int x = 0; x < pattern.length; x++)
  for (int y = 0; y < pattern[x].length; y++)
    if (pattern[x][y] == 1) {
      board[x + offsetX][y + offsetY].setNextState(true);
    } else {
      board[x + offsetX][y + offsetY].setNextState(false);
    }
    gc.setFill(board[x + offsetX][y + offsetY].getState() ? Color.rgb(244, 92, 66) : Color.LIGHTGRAY);
    gc.fillRect((x + offsetX) * 10, (y + offsetY) * 10, 9, 9);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < pattern.length; x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < pattern[x].length; y++) {
    int bx = x + 30,
        by = y + 30;
    if (pattern[x][y] == 1) {
      board[bx][by].setNextState(true);
    } else {
      board[bx][by].setNextState(false);
    }
    ...
```

and so on.

Comment: I'm trying to do this, but I get an array index out of bounds error. I also tried  if (pattern[x - patternX][y - patternY]), as the pattern is only 3x3, but that gives me same error